# Какая из двух формул вычисления среднего элемента правильнее?

Tags: java, двоичный-поиск

В разных источниках по бинарному поиску встретил две формулы поиска
среднего элемента. Вроде результаты одинаковы. Вторая проще для запоминания и работы.

Какая из низ правильная и в чем особенности применения?

```
Вариант №1:

 int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;

Вариант №2:

  int middleIndex = (firstIndex + lastIndex) / 2;
```

Comment: Если раскрыть скобки, то окажется, что обе формулы абсолютно одинаковы

Comment: Не окажется, более того будут разные результаты в зависимости от входных данных.

Comment: @NowhereMan А пример? Переполнение не рассматриваем.

Comment: @rotabor, а почему собственно не рассматривать переполнение?

Comment: @NowhereMan Просто про него уже написали

Answer (score 3):

Давайте исследуем формулы. Преобразуем первую формулу с учётом целочисленной арифметики. Умножим оба слагаемых на 4 - это не изменит их значение:

```
low + (high - low) / 2 = 4 * low / 4 + 2 * (high - low) / 4
    = (4 * low + 2 * high - 2 * low) / 4 = (2 * high + 2 * low) / 4
    = (low + high) / 2
```

Получается, формулы эквивалентны. *Единственная разница между ними состоит в том, что первая никогда не вызовет переполнения при вычислении (при естественном условии low <= high), а вторая может вызвать.*

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что есть вероятность того, что сумма `(firstIndex + lastIndex)` может вызвать переполнение при значениях индексов, близких к `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (пример - сортировка одним из методов "разделяй и властвуй" или бинарный поиск по массиву байтов длиной 1200000000). А вариант с разностью, если параметры не перепутаны, от этого недостатка не страдает.

Данная проблема, например, рассматривается в книге Джона Бентли "Жемчужины программирования", где он указывает на неё как на типичную ошибку в реализации двоичного поиска, которая оставалась незамеченной десятки лет. Поскольку массивы редко бывают размером почти во всю доступную память, то в реальной работе встретить эту беду трудно. Но возможно.

Comment: С уважением отношусь как к Джону Б,, так и к MBo, но объяснение притянуто за уши. Любые вычисления нужно анализировать на промежуточные переполнения и стараться их избегать. Кто же прямо по писаному вычисляет? Поскольку обе формулы эквиваленты, то о какой-то разнице говорить нельзя, а просто нужно вычислять срединное значение как сумму половин.

Comment: Математически эквивалентны, а в машинной арифметике - нет. `Кто же прямо по писаному вычисляет?` - вот же как раз и пример, что можно не по-писаному, а чуть изменить, и избавиться от возможной ошибки. `просто нужно вычислять срединное значение как сумму половин` - а вот и нет, сумма половин хранит в себе другую ловушку - проверьте на 5 и 7